# Get image name from database in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have database, with columns image and alttag. I want to use them in laravel blade view. I try something like this:

```
{{ HTML::image('images/{{ $item->image }}', $alt="{{ $item->alttag }}") }}
```

But syntax isn't correct. If i just echo image and alttag like this:

```
<h1>{{ $item->alttag }}</h1>
```

then they are correct.  I wonder what is wrong in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used blade syntax in a PHP string. Watch the compiled blade templates to see where you did go wrong.

In short. Try this:

```
{{ HTML::image('images/'. $item->image, $alt = $item->alttag) }}
```

or equally short:

```
{{ HTML::image("images/{$item->image}", $alt = $item->alttag) }}
```